# Finding the opening of a 3D surface

Tags: python, math, numpy, geometry

I have an array `sphere` holding cartesian coordinates XYZ. Each row is one point of the surface of an object. I'd like to find the opening of that surface and rotate the object so that the x-axis points out of the opening.

I'm working with python and numpy, but a general approach is just as good as a specific implementation.

Here's what I currently have. The x-axis is colored red, the origin is colored green:

[image]

And here's what I would like to get:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you want to apply a rotation matrix to your data. However, you'll also need to find the rotation matrix.

In this case, it's easier to skip directly to working with the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix.  This is basically a principal components approach.  If we determine the principal components of your data and rotate things into that coordinate system, we'll effectively do what you want.

To start out with, let's generate an example similar to yours:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def main():
    x, y, z = generate_data()
    plot(x, y, z)
    plt.show()

def generate_data():
    lat, lon = np.radians(np.mgrid[-90:90:20j, 0:180:20j])
    lon -= np.radians(40)
    z = np.cos(lat) * np.cos(lon)
    x = np.cos(lat) * np.sin(lon)
    y = np.sin(lat)
    return x, y, z

def plot(x, y, z):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'), facecolor='w')
    artist = ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker='o', color='y')
    ax.set(xlim=[-1.1, 1.1], ylim=[-1.1, 1.1], zlim=[-1.1, 1.1], aspect=1)
    ax.set(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', zlabel='Z')
    return artist

main()
```

[image]

Now we can rotate things based on the principal coordinates:

```
def reorient(x, y, z):
    xyz = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel()])
    cov = np.cov(xyz)

    # Find the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix
    vals, vecs = np.linalg.eigh(cov)
    idx = np.argsort(vals)
    # The eigenvalues vals are not needed below, but this puts them in
    # the same order as the eigenvectors, should they be needed in future
    # versions of this code:
    vals, vecs = vals[idx], vecs[:, idx]

    # In this case, we actually want the second eigenvector to be the x-axis
    vecs = vecs[:, [1, 0, 2]]

    # Now let's perform a change-of-basis into the new coordinate system
    return np.linalg.inv(vecs).dot(xyz)
```

And plot the results:

```
def main():
    x, y, z = generate_data()
    plot(*reorient(x, y, z))
    plt.show()
```

[image]

One note: I've implicitly assumed that your data is already centered on the point at which the rotation will occur.  If that's not the case, you'd need to subtract the rotation point (e.g. the mean) before calculating the covariance matrix and then add it back in after the change of basis.

Comment: This is a high-quality implementation of the proposed method (Principal Components). However, it would not work exactly as intended if the sphere was replaced by an oblong shape (like a half football ball), and would not work at all if the shape was complex, even if it has an obvious (for humans) opening, right?

Comment: @EOL - No, not in general. It's not looking for an opening. However, an oblong shape should still be okay, though you'd need to change which eigenvector you place along the x axis. A surface reconstruction algorithm should be better for the fully general case. Then you could inspect the surface for concavity and openings. That's rather complex, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one idea. Take the convex hull of your points. If the "opening" of your surface is planar, then that opening will be covered with nearly coplanar faces in the convex hull. Then the normal vectors to all the faces will have a distinct pattern, that can help identify the boundary.

---

[image: HemiSphere]

---